# What are all the costumes?

Tags: gravity-rush

I've beaten the main game and I still only have Kat's normal outfit and the schoolgirl outfit. I know that there's a couple DLCs which bring their own outfits, but since they introduced changing clothes in the main game, I assumed there would be more outfits.

Are there more outfits in the main game? What are all the outfits in total and how do you get them?

Answer (score 2):

As i know, the two costumes you're talking about are the only one in the main game.

[These Guys here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/620274-gravity-rush/63151565/706504919) are supporting my conclusion.

If i'm right there should be a total of [five costumes](http://www.psvitaa.com/upload/2012-04/120410181093301.jpg) available but i'm not sure how to unlock them.

Comment: I know of maid and military costumes from DLC, there may be a third DLC I'm forgetting

Comment: There're three DLC's.The Spy DLC, the military and the Maid DLC. Source: http://m.ign.com/wikis/gravity-rush/DLC

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 DLC Costumes from the PSN Store (Australian one), they are

- Maid
- Spy
- Military

these are unlocked by doing the DLC Missions that came with the packs, i would assume during the first mission as i have only obtains the Maid one at the moment

You also have Kat's normal outfit and from what your question entails, there is a Schoolgirl one which i don't know how to unlock

When you get the tutorial image about costumes and how to change into them after getting one, the image of the menu in Kat's House shows there are 5 total

I was actually going to ask what the 5th one is but as your question states, it seems to be a schoolgirl one, would like to know how to get it

Also note that information on DLC is based off Australian PSN Store Availability, it is very possible that there may be more DLC available in another region (Agarest Generations of War Zero DLC is available in the UK but not Australia despite UK Games being fully compatible with Australian DLC and vice versa)

Comment: the schoolgirl one is unlocked through the story, you should get it at some point automatically

Comment: @spartacus thanks, thought it might have been a pre-order Bonus DLC like the Kamidori Alchemy Miester Gold Disk's "God Slayer" Armour (Yuela), "Elf Princess" Armour (Serawi) and "Little Demon" Armour (Emilita) which is totally possible you only get 1....Emilita's Armour name may be wrong but it's based off Lily from Dungeon Miester